# PHP program can't execute piCamera function in Python script

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi, picamera

I am making a php program that executes a Python script in which a camera is recording. The camera is plugged to a Raspberry Pi.
Here is the Python script (I am using Python3) :

```
#import time
import datetime
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from picamera import PiCamera


T = 0
N = 0
A = 0

print("0")

TITLE = "maelan" #sys.argv[1]
S = 1 #sys.argv[2]
USER_NAME = "MaElAn" #sys.argv[3]
TIME = int(S)
#SRC = './src'
#DST = './mp4'
VIDEO_IN = TITLE + ".mp4"
PATH_VID = "/var/www/html/superv/public/user_" + USER_NAME + "/"
NEW_PATH_VID = PATH_VID + "exp_" + TITLE + "/"
#IMG = TITLE + "_" + str(T)

print("1")

if not os.path.exists(NEW_PATH_VID + "img"):
    os.makedirs(NEW_PATH_VID + "img")
print("1.5")
if not os.path.exists(PATH_VID + "exp_" + TITLE):
    os.system("mkdir " + PATH_VID + "exp_" + TITLE)
print("1.75")

VIDEO_OUT = NEW_PATH_VID + "compressed_" + TITLE + ".mp4"

#print (sys.argv)

print("2")
#os.system("/usr/bin/octave /home/pi/SOE/Frames/analyser.m")


CAMERA = PiCamera()
print("3")
CAMERA.resolution = (1280, 720)
CAMERA.framerate = 25
CAMERA.image_effect = "negative"
#CAMERA.start_preview()
CAMERA.start_recording(TITLE + ".h264")

#Horodatage dynamique
while T < TIME:
    #CAMERA.capture("/home/pi/SOE/img/" + IMG + ".jpg")
    NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
    CAMERA.annotate_text = NOW.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S " + TITLE)
    CAMERA.wait_recording(1)
    T = T + 1

CAMERA.stop_recording()
#CAMERA.stop_preview()
print("3")
```

I call this scrip via a php shell_exec function. Here is the php code :

```
$out=shell_exec('progVideo.py');
echo $out;
```

The python script executes well, until this line :

```
CAMERA = PiCamera()
```

I feel like php doesn't have permissions to access the camera plugged to the Raspberry.I did `chmod 777 /var/www` and `chmod 777 /dev/vchiq` but nothing works. The camera doesn't record anything. Pls help :)

Comment: You said it executes well until that line but haven't told us what happens then. Is there an error?

Comment: Well, you see all the print functions in the python script ? It is just for debug. It prints all the numbers until the print("3") line, which means the program stops right when it tries to initialise the picamera

Comment: So it's a hang rather than an exception/crash? It's important to be specific in your description.

Comment: Yes it is a hang. The program doesn't crash, it just stops. What could be the problem ?

Comment: I don't know. There are other people discussing similar issues (e.g. [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59528) and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=158258) and I know from experience that it'll hang if it gets at all annoyed. Do the command-line capture applications work? If they also hang then it could be a hardware issue (insufficient power supply, cable not inserted correctly, etc). Software issues can include invalid configuration and not closing the camera after using it.

Comment: Well, the thing is, when I execute the python script via cmd line, it works (the camera records anything). But when I call the script from php, it hangs. Which is why I'm assuming php doesn't have the right to access the video library. It might be a permission problem.

Comment: Is the PHP script running from a webserver or from terminal? If it's running from webserver which user is it running with? Have you tried running the PHP script from command line to see if it works correctly?

Have you tried using Python Try/Except to debug?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato The php is running from a webserver (apache2) and the user that uses it is the admin. How do you execute a php script from command line ? I thought we could only see the result via a web browser...